# AOSP Build Error: instances are in the device manifest but not specified in framework compatibility matrix:

Tags: android, android-source

FAILED: ninja: 'device/google/cuttlefish/framework_compatibility_matrix.xml', needed by 'out/ target/product/vsoc_x86_64_only/gen/ETC/framework_compatibility_matrix.device.xml_intermediates/compatibi lity_natrix.device.xml', missing and no known rule to make it ninja failed with: exit status

I am getting the above error while I tried to include matrix in mk file. I am trying in AOSP14.What exactly I need to change, to fix this issue? Is this error related to HIDL to AIDL conversion?

Update deprecated HALs to the latest version.
Check for any typos in device manifest or framework compatibility matrices with FCM version >= 8.
For new platform HALs, add them to any framework compatibility matrix with FCM version >= 8 where applicable.
For device-specific HALs, add to DEVICE_FRAMEWORK_COMPATIBILITY_MATRIX_FILE or DEVICE_PRODUCT_COMPATIBILITY_MATRIX_FILE.: Success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.